# Modifying dictionary attributes in jinja2

Tags: python, dictionary, pyramid, jinja2

Suppose I pass a dictionary to my jinja2 template.
In the view I have something like

```
d = {}
#set other template stuff into d
get_params['cri'] = 'time'
get_params['order'] = 'asc'
d['get_params'] = get_params
return d
```

In the template I need to change the value of keys of get_params. The logical thing

```
{% set get_params.cri='src' %}
```

fails with an error

```
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token '=', got '.'
```

My question is how do I modify the values passed to a dictionary in jinja2

(This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703013/how-can-i-modify-merge-jinja2-dictionaries), but I find the answer confusing and it only answers the merging part)

**Answer EDIT:**

Jinja2 provides the 'do' extension. To add that extension to pyramid, do the following in the `__init__.py` file

```
#This line is alreadythere
config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
#Add this line
config.add_jinja2_extension('jinja2.ext.do')
```

In the template

```
{% do get_params.update({'cri':'src'}) %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is that you cannot perform assignments in jinja2. What you can do however (as suggested in the other post that you linked) is to call a do block and perform an update operation (update is a method of any dict in python; http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update).

Comment: I got the update part (Actually doing it now in {{ }} tags but that prints None). How do I use a {% do %} block. Code will be much appreciated. Espicially how to enable jinja2 extensions from pyramid