# Do statement not working in jinja

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I'm altering an existing web interface to view ROBOT doc libraries, which uses a mixture of jinja (Python inside HTML) and HTML. I have never worked with jinja or HTML before and am having issues getting even a simple test case to work. When the browser loads the docs, I want our project's directory structure for the docs to be preserved to make finding things easier, and so I want to use jinja to create the dir structure. Here is a snippet of the code I'm working with:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<div class="well" id="left">
  <ul class="list-group list-unstyled">
    {% set collection_list = [] %}
    {% for collection in data.hierarchy %}
      {% if collection.collection_id|string == data.collection_id|string %}
          {% do collection_list.append(collection.path) %}
      {% else %}
        {% for link in collection.path_chain %}
          <li>
          <label class="tree-toggler nav-header"
                 title="file path: {{collection.path}}">{{link}}</label>
          <ul class="list-group  tree collapse"
              id={{link}}>
              </ul>
        {% endfor %}
          </li>
      {% endif %}
```

...there's more after that, but this is where I hit the error. It sets the collection_list var fine, and the if statements work, but when it goes to execute the 'do' statement it fails with:

**TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'do'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'elif' or 'else' or 'endif'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'if'.**

I don't believe this is an unclosed loop or something because if I replace the do statement with a simple test print statement, it works. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The first question is, does Jinja have a 'do' statement? I ask because Python doesn't, as far as I know.

Comment: Supposedly it does - I've found examples such as '{% do navigation.append('a string') %}', though perhaps it's a version/missing extension thing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [template documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/templates/#expression-statement):

> #### Expression Statement
>
> If the expression-statement extension is loaded, a tag called `do` is available that works exactly like the regular variable expression (`{{ ... }}`); except it doesn’t print anything. This can be used to modify lists:
>
> ```
> {% do navigation.append('a string') %}
> ```

You need to enable the [Expression statement extension](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/extensions/#expression-statement) for this to work.

You didn't show how you load the Jinja2 environment, but loading extensions takes place via the `extensions` argument to the [`Environment()` class](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/extensions/#adding-extensions):

```
jinja_env = Environment(extensions=['jinja2.ext.do'])
```

Comment: Ah, I see - I didn't realize it wasn't included. Sorry about that, I'll track down where in the code it gets loaded and add the extension.

Comment: To load this extension in a Flask app, add `app.jinja_env.add_extension('jinja2.ext.do')` somewhere during app initialization.

Comment: Maybe there is no way around this but, its causing white space to be spit out `{% do navigation.append('a string') %}` Its not outputting None, but I have a good chunk of just newlines now, which I would prefer not to have.

Comment: @Melendowski: Jinja gives you [plenty of control over whitespace](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#whitespace-control); use `{%-` instead of `{%` to remove whitespace before the block, and using `-%}` instead of `%}` will remove any whitespace following the block.