# How to set a variable in the flask context from a jinja macro?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I would like to create a macro which needs to keep track if it was ever called before. Therefore I would have to set a variable in the request context in my macro, but I don't have an idea how I could do that. Something like:

```
{% macro my_macro() -%}
    {% set g.foo = "bar" %}   <-- Error
    {{ g.get('foo') }}
{%- endmacro %}
```

The above results in an `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateRuntimeError: cannot assign attribute on non-namespace object` error.

I am aware that this might be an abuse of the macro concept and would also be open for other solutions. I want to keep track of the macro use, so I can output some required javascript for the macro at most one time, or not at all if the macro wasn't used.

Answer (score 2):

There [is a workaround](https://github.com/Reservix/ansible-style-guide/wiki/Jinja2-Syntax) to use a `do` rather than `set` command:

```
{% do g.update({"foo": "bar"}) %}
```

Note that the `do` command is [not enabled](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/extensions/#expression-statement) by default, so for this to work you must enable `jinja2.ext.do` as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39858522/4651668).