# How do I execute a custom filter that returns no output without assigning to a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I have a custom filter that updates a global variable in my code and does some other stuff when called. It returns no output.

I just want to call it inside a template without assigning the output to a variable.

Doing this works but I want to remove the unnecessary variable assignment:

```
{%- set unused = {'one': 'aaa', "two": "bbb", 'three': 'ccc'} | get_env_var -%}
```

I've tried the following:

```
{%- {'one': 'aaa', "two": "bbb", 'three': 'ccc'} | get_env_var -%}
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: tag name expected
```

```
{{'one': 'aaa', "two": "bbb", 'three': 'ccc'} | get_env_var}
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'
```

```
{{{'one': 'aaa', "two": "bbb", 'three': 'ccc'} | get_env_var}}
yaml.composer.ComposerError: expected a single document in the stream
in "<unicode string>", line 3, column 1:
    ccc
    ^
but found another document
  in "<unicode string>", line 4, column 1:
    ---
    ^
```

How do I just execute a custom filter and not capture its output?

Comment: Why not set the global variable rather than `unused`?

Comment: It sets an env var and does other things as well. I just want to execute it in the template and not do anything else in jinja code.

Comment: Use the `do` statement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39858522/2123530

Comment: do is what I needed. You can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your environment already have the [*expression statement* extension](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/extensions/#expression-statement) enabled, then the expression statement — `{% do ... %}` — is the best fit for your use case.

As pointed [in the documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#expression-statement), it acts like a variable expression — `{{ ... }}` — but won't print anything.

The usage in your case would be something like:

```
{%- do {
    'one': 'aaa', 
    'two': 'bbb', 
    'three': 'ccc'
} | get_env_var -%}
```